# List running software from registry in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to code an application in VC++ which lists the current running applications on my system.

By using the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall`, I'm able to list the current installed applications on my system.

Is there any way to list which ones of these applications that are running?

Comment: The registry is for stable information, not for things that can change every second. That's why the short answer is "no".

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't. The registry key you mention only references the installation redistribution package and not the installed and running executable file(s). There are no connections between the installation registry details and the executable that is actually running after an installation has completed and the software started. Only way to achive this is to parse the installation package files and try to extract the executable name & path from it - if even possible.

Comment: hey look at out here..we can though not from registry  but yes we can.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx..look

Comment: @user3471546 Your link don't work, here it is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Your link only explains how to _enumerate processes_ and not how to _find what running process is related to which installation redistribution package_ (which is the main problem you are facing). If you can't find the name and path of the running executable from the registry information then you don't know which running process to find - do get what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to iterate through the list of currently running processes using [Process Walking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684887%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)